# How to force Service-worker to request route from network after loading it from cache?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, service-worker

I'm using [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox), which is a library for service-worker provided by Google. I'd like to combine the cacheFirst strategy (see readme in link above) with a fetch from network after successfully loading a content from cache. Is it possible? So for example smth like:

```
toolbox.router.get('/api/currentUserID',toolbox.cacheFirst).then(fetchFromNetwork());
```

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [toolbox.fastest](https://github.com/googlechrome/sw-toolbox#toolboxfastest) that will get the cache response or the network response, which ever is fastest (which will almost certainly always be the cache) and then update the cache with the response from the network.

Comment: @Guant thanks for your answer :) I'm not really sure if it works for me. In my service-worker there's following route defined: 

`toolbox.router.get('/api/threads/*', toolbox.fastest); `

  

However debugger says: 

`sw-toolbox:18 [sw-toolbox] Strategy: fastest [http://localhost:3000/api/threads/100004344516230/portion/1]
sw-toolbox:18 [sw-toolbox] Strategy: cache only [http://localhost:3000/api/threads/100004344516230/portion/1]`

So it's actually using cacheOnly only :)

Is it fine?

Comment: Yeah that's fine because it makes one request for just the cache and one request to the network but it does it at the same time.